# Calculate the index of the following vector fields

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Calculate the index of the following vector fields $V: \mathbb R ^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R ^2 $ at the point $0$.

$1.$ $V(x,y) = (-y,x)$

$2.$  $V(x,y)=(-y-x,x-y)$

### My attempt

Definition. Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R ^m$ be an open and let $V:A \rightarrow \mathbb R ^m$ be a smooth vector field with an isolated critical point $c \in A$. The **index** $\iota(V;c)$ of $V$ at $c$ is the degree of the function

$$ \partial \bar{V_\iota (c)} \rightarrow^{\phi_\epsilon} S^{m-1}$$
$$x \mapsto \frac{V_x}{|V_x|}$$

Where $\epsilon >0$ is small enough so that the vector field $V$ vanishes nowhee on $V_\epsilon (c)$\ $\{c\}$.

This definition is really a mouthful and to be honest I am finding it difficult to understand. But let me try to go on with the problem.

$1.$ $V(x,y) = (-y,x)$

Let $c=0$, so $0$ is an isolated point. So there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $V$ restricted to the closed disk $\bar{V_\epsilon (0)}$ vanishes nowhere except at $0$. Let $\epsilon =1$

Don't know how to proceed...

### Edit: Attempt 2

The matrix associated with this vector field is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\quad,$$

This corresponds to a rotation of $\pi/2$ radians, since according to the rotation matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\pi/2) &- \sin(\pi/2) \\ \sin(\pi/2) & \sin(\pi/2) \end{pmatrix}\quad=\quad\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Letting $\epsilon = 1$ gives you the unit circle.

Still not sure why the degree of $\phi$ at 0 is $1$

Also not sure why $(1,0)$ is a regular value

Answer (score 2):

These functions are linear and represented by the matrices

> $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\quad,\quad\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

so the degree is just $1$ as you would expect from any linear function since the functions are **globally** injective.

Comment: how are you getting these matrices? I am taking a real analysis class and my linear algebra skills are a bit rusty.

Comment: @combostudent I looked at the coefficients in your expression, $(f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y))$ in the first instance $f_1(x,y) = -y = (0)x + (-1) y$ so that gave my my first row, same thing for the second row as $(1)x + (0)y$. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: great help on the matrices part! Now, I do have an answer in front of me that i peaked at and it said that (for #1) the function $\phi: \partial \bar{V_\epsilon (0)} \rightarrow S^1$ represents a $\pi/2$ rotation here. Why is that? and why is that relevant?

Comment: @combostudent That's just looking at what a rotation matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$ Put in $\theta=\pi/2$. It's not necessarily relevant unless you happen to be using that fact to establish the same fact as I already did: that the function is globally injective.

Comment: is the rotation matrix the same for any problem?

Comment: also, why is (1,0) a regular value here?

Comment: @combostudent every problem is different. And you can just follow the definition of a regular value

Comment: is it because $V(1,0)= (0,1)$ and $V(0,1)=(-1,0)$ which if you start at $(1,0)$ on the unit circle and end at $(-1,0)$ it give you the $\pi/2$ rotation?

Comment: @combostudent don't try and use random facts, your best friends are definitions. Regular points are non-critical points.